# How can I transform some items values into new items value?

Tags: filter, ansible, jinja2

This is my var:

```yaml
    zones:
      - hostname: host10
        cname: "{{cname1|default(omit)}}"
        zone: ["v120","v121","linux"]
        ips: 8
      - hostname: host11
        cname: "{{cname2|default(omit)}}"
        zone: ["v120","v121"]
        ips: 10
      - hostname: host12
        zone: [linux]
        ips: 88
```

How can I build the same var with little replacement on zones.zone (substitute v120 to 120, v121 to 121, linux to v120):

```yaml
    zones:
      - hostname: host10
        cname: "{{cname1|default(omit)}}"
        zone: ["120","121","120"]
        ips: 8
      - hostname: host11
        cname: "{{cname2|default(omit)}}"
        zone: ["120","121"]
        ips: 10
      - hostname: host12
        zone: [120]
        ips: 88
```

I tried a lot of combinations with some filters, in particulary "combine" and "regex_replace"

```sh
   regex_replace('^v(.*)$', '\\1')
```

but never succeded to get the final objective. It seemed to be so simple to do, I must miss something...

Comment: Do you have your var in a playbook, in a template? Are you trying with a playbook? Describe with detail what you have and what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary *substitute* and iterate *zones*. In each iteration extract substituted *zone*, combine the dictionary with the *item* and concatenate the list *zones2*. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        zones2: "{{ zones2|default([]) +
                    [item|combine({'zone': zone})] }}"
      loop: "{{ zones }}"
      vars:
        zone: "{{ item.zone|map('extract', substitute)|list }}"
        substitute:
          v120: 120
          v121: 121
          linux: 120
    - debug:
        var: zones2
```

gives

```yaml
  zones2:
  - hostname: host10
    ips: 8
    zone:
    - 120
    - 121
    - 120
  - hostname: host11
    ips: 10
    zone:
    - 120
    - 121
  - hostname: host12
    ips: 88
    zone:
    - 120
```

---

Mapping *regex_replace*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        zones2: "{{ zones2|default([]) +
                    [item|combine({'zone': zone})] }}"
      loop: "{{ zones }}"
      vars:
        zone: "{{ item.zone|
                  map('regex_replace', regex, replace)|
                  map('regex_replace', regex2, replace2)|
                  list }}"
        regex: '^v(.*)$'
        replace: '\1'
        regex2: '^linux$'
        replace2: '120'
    - debug:
        var: zones2
```

gives

```yaml
  zones2:
  - hostname: host10
    ips: 8
    zone:
    - '120'
    - '121'
    - '120'
  - hostname: host11
    ips: 10
    zone:
    - '120'
    - '121'
  - hostname: host12
    ips: 88
    zone:
    - '120'
```

---

**"*Understand what does the extract filter*"**

Show the results of the [*extract*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) filter

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ item.zone|to_yaml }}{{ zone|to_yaml }}
      loop: "{{ zones }}"
      vars:
        zone: "{{ item.zone|map('extract', substitute)| list }}"
        substitute:
          v120: 120
          v121: 121
          linux: 120
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    [v120, v121, linux]
    [120, 121, 120]

  msg: |-
    [v120, v121]
    [120, 121]

  msg: |-
    [linux]
    [120]
```

---

**"*Understand what does the combine solution*"**

Show the results of the [*combine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) filter

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item|combine({'zone': zone})|
                 to_yaml}}"
      loop: "{{ zones }}"
      vars:
        zone: "{{ item.zone|map('extract', substitute)| list }}"
        substitute:
          v120: 120
          v121: 121
          linux: 120
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    cname: __omit_place_holder__3938838202c238b505bfc39af57a09b4fe9972f6
    hostname: host10
    ips: 8
    zone: [120, 121, 120]

  msg: |-
    cname: __omit_place_holder__3938838202c238b505bfc39af57a09b4fe9972f6
    hostname: host11
    ips: 10
    zone: [120, 121]

  msg: |-
    hostname: host12
    ips: 88
    zone: [120]
```

---

**"*"zones2": "[AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined]" How can you explian that?*"**

The code below works as expected

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        zones2: "{{ item.zone|map('extract', substitute)|list }}"
      loop: "{{ zones }}"
      register: zones_list
      vars:
        substitute:
          v120: 120
          v121: 121
          linux: 120
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ zones_list.results|map(attribute='ansible_facts')|list|
                 to_yaml }}"
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    - zones2: [120, 121, 120]
    - zones2: [120, 121]
    - zones2: [120]
```

Comment: See [Lazy Evaluation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html).  The system takes care of proper variables' evaluation, e.g. if *zone* contains *item* it will be evaluated in each iteration.

Comment: To understand what does the combine solution, I isolated the substitute loop:    `- set_fact:
        zones2: "{{ item.zone|map('extract', substitute)|list }}"
        substitute:
          v120: 120
          v121: 121
          linux: 120
      loop: "{{zones}}"
      register: zones_list
    - debug:
        msg: "{{zones_list.results|map(attribute='ansible_facts')|list}}"` but the debug msg says `"zones2": "[AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined]"` for the first iteration. What is curious is that this piece of code included in your playbook works great. How can you explian that?

Comment: I have no explanation. The formating of your example is not clear. I've added debug examples anyway. Open a new question if have other issues.

Comment: The answer was very simple, I missed the "vars" items before "substitute"... Thank you, everything is clear and comprehensive now, you helped me a lot.